# Difference between timings as logged by postgresql and psql timings

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have a python application which uses postgresql (9.4.6) as a backend. I configured postgresql logging to log all queries over one second, and noticed some very straightforward `SELECT` queries in the log, running in around 1.5s (ranging from 0.8s to over 5s)

I tried to run them in `psql` to `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` etc... but then they ran in around 20ms, with a very simple exec plan. The query itself looks like :

```
SELECT * FROM <my_table> where <indexed_column> IN (<list of values>)
```

The queries from the python application are executed in a readonly transaction, and in both cases the average load on the database was similar.

I noticed that the CPU load seems higher than it should be, considering the load. The behaviour seems consistent (i.e. the same query from the application is always ~100 times longer than on psql).

What could explain the observed difference of timings?

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` measure the time **only** on the server. **Without** the time for transferring the data. The 5 seconds you see are caused by network latency and your application processing the result

Comment: The 5s correspond to the execution time which is logged on the postgresql server, not the application one.